# Magento incorrect 404 redirect

Tags: php, magento, redirect, http-status-code-404

Magento is redirecting any 404 errors to the admin login.  In the admin settings I have the no route setting set to a CMS page that I confirmed exists.

I have been fighting with this for a week.  Cleared cache, reindex, rebuilt url rewrites, etc...

If there is a way to completely bypass magento handling 404 I can do this through htaccess just to get it working.

Ideas?

I also went through and disabled any custom modules I had installed to see if they were affecting it.  No luck there.

Checked apache/php logs as well as both exception and system logs generated from Magento.  Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had experienced a "4xx Error", it means the error occurred on the user/client side.
If you had experienced a "5xx Error", it means the error occurred on the server side.

```
404 Not Found
```

> The requested resource could not be found but may be available again
>   in the future.[2] Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.

I'm not sure, but it sounds like the error is in your controller. You are calling a controller action that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You has checked the settings?

Admin->System->Config->Web->Default Pages

Default No-route URL should be set to 'cms/index/noRoute'

The drop down beneath that show be your 404 page.

Of course you can put the noRoute to your own module, simply put 'yourmodule/yourindexcontroller/whateveraction' in the box.

Comment: yeah, that is what it is set to "cms/index/noRoute" Also tried even changing the CMS page tot he home page.  Still redirects to 404

Comment: Maybe something up with it that I am not getting. Try put customer/account in the box and see if that redirects to the right place - customer account login.

Comment: ...and make sure the cache is off.

Comment: No, it doesnt.  Like it is completely ignoring those settings :(

Comment: You are going to have to debug: http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_standard_router

Comment: Thats a bit over my head.  Isn't there a way to completely bypass magento 404 routing and use my own htaccess rule?

Comment: No is the short answer! You are going to have to see what it routes to and why. You can obviously override noRoute in cms but I don't think you are getting that far in the routing.

Comment: So I ran a debug.  It does appear to be going into the noRoute controller.  I guess I will try over writing now